# Accessibility Service : AudioManager.AudioRecordingCallback on the AudioRecord or MediaRecorder

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I am trying to record the audio via Accessibility as [In Android developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/sharing-audio-input#pre-behavior)  mentioned

**"The app can capture audio if it is an accessibility service."**

Below is my code For Accessibility Service :

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {
    private static final String TAG="MyAccessibilityService";
    public static final String START_RECORDING="START_RECORDING";
    public static final String STOP_RECORDING="STOP_RECORDING";

    private Context context;

    MediaRecorder recorder;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG,"MyAccessibilityService Salesken Started ...");
        context=this;

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            switch (action) {
                case START_RECORDING:
                    Log.d(TAG,"Start Recording");
                    String contact = intent.getStringExtra("contact");

                    startRecorder(contact);
                    break;
                case STOP_RECORDING:

                    Log.d(TAG,"Stop Recording");

                    stopRecorder();
                    break;
            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void stopRecorder() {
        if(recorder != null){
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();
        }
    }

    private void startRecorder(String contact) {
        String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
        String fileName =contact +"-"+timestamp+".pcm";
        MediaSaver mediaSaver = new MediaSaver(context).setParentDirectoryName("AudioRecording").
                setFileNameKeepOriginalExtension(fileName).
                setExternal(MediaSaver.isExternalStorageReadable());
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(mediaSaver.pathFile().getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        recorder.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {

    }




    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
      stopRecorder();
    }


}
```

Every time when i call START_RECORDING to my Accessibility Service i am getting below exception in the service

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4222)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:231)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1984)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.native_start(Native Method)
```

I have below mention permission in my Manifest :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

I am not sure how to use AudioManager.AudioRecordingCallback on the AudioRecord or MediaRecorder so that it can capture Voice Call Audio.

Comment: what is media saver?

Comment: Its a Utility Class which saves data into a file with metadata like file name, directory name

Comment: Is it working on android 12? I have tried a lot of answers on stack overflow but they are not working. Can you share a sample code?

Answer (score 1):

MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL for system apps.

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
```

> Capturing from VOICE_CALL source requires the Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT permission. This permission is reserved for use by system components and is not available to third-party applications.

[VOICE_CALL Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource#VOICE_CALL)

You can use VOICE_RECOGNITION source after activate Accesibility Service.

However, it will still not work in some countries or some physical devices. There are legal issues, so Samsung, Huawei, Xiaomi will act differently.

```
  recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION);
```